# "unable to start activity component info" android xml parsing

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a xml parsing for android

I follow this tutorial to make it :

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

When I run the app I get this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aka.bdb/com.aka.bdb.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I made ListView id:list but I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list with `@android:id/list`, not `@+id/list`.

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@android:+id/list').

Comment: `@android:id/list`. The plus does not belong there, sorry for the typo.

Comment: thank yout, Now I get this error : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException :(

Comment: This is another error and not related to this one. Accept the answer and create a new one. 
Little hint for your error, don't do the download / networking on the UI thread, create a new one.

Comment: the problem is if I run the source code on the tutorial the app start fine, but when I make own classes I get errors :(

Comment: Here is a link to the answer for your 'next' problem, that Leandros hinted about: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html